# what is the difference between the following Inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, virtual-functions

Here is the simple inheritance

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string Draw()
    {
        return "Draw from BaseClass";
    }
}

public class ChildClass:BaseClass
{
    public string Draw()
    {
        return "Draw from ChildClass";
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   ChildClass c = new ChildClass();
   console.writeline(c.Draw());
}
```

The above implementation will print 
Draw from Childclass

Here is the usage with the override

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual string Draw()
    {
        return "Draw from BaseClass";
    }
}

public class ChildClass:BaseClass
{
    public override string Draw()
    {
        return "Draw from ChildClass";
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   ChildClass c = new ChildClass();
   console.writeline(c.Draw());
}
```

The above implementation will print 
Draw from Childclass

So what is the difference between above 2 Inheritance Implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second snippet Draw is declared to be virtual, this means that you can call the inherited method from a variable of type `BaseClass`.

```
BaseClass b = new ChildClass ();

b.Draw () // will call ChildClass.Draw
```

---

**Documentation**

- [msdn - 10.5.3 Virtual methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [The C# Station Tutorial - Lesson 9: Polymorphism](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/lesson09.aspx)

*Funny thing.. the second link in the list above uses the same snippets as you've provided.*

Comment: Could be worth mentioning that the first snippet is known as 'method hiding' and that the compiler generates a CS0108 warning when method hiding is used without the new keyword.

Answer (score 0):

In the first implementation, if you call `Draw()` from inside `BaseClass`, the output will be "Draw from Base Class". But in the second implementation it will be "Draw from Child Class". Here is an explanation:
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/04/09/60168.aspx